# Cannot install Freeform after upgrade

Tags: solspace-freeform, upgrade

I've just upgraded a large site from EE 1.6.8 to 2.9.2 and now cannot install Freeform.

There was an install of Freeform on the old site pre-upgrade. Once the upgrade was complete I tried to upgrade Freeform but kept getting errors.

I then removed Freeform entirely from the upgraded site but still get errors, I've dropped all of the tables in the DB related to Freeform but still get this:

```
{"error":"
Error Number: 1146<\/p>\n\n

Table 'darrenc_dsx14.exp_freeform_preferences' doesn't exist<\/p>\n\n

SELECT `preference_name`, `preference_value`\nFROM (`exp_freeform_preferences`)\nWHERE `site_id` = '0'<\/p>\n\n

Filename: third_party\/freeform\/models\/freeform_model.php<\/p>\n\n

Line Number: 330<\/p>"}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: When you say "I then removed FreeForm entirely" what do you mean exactly?  Have you tried removing the directory `third_party/freeform`?  Be sure you have a back up or try it on a dev site first.

Comment: Yes. All files related to Freeform have been removed from the system/third_party directory and also from the themes/third_party directory.

Comment: Strange.  Your error seems to indicate that the third party files are still there.  Do you see FreeForm still listed in the Control Panel under Add-Ons?  There's an accessory and a module.

Comment: Yes it's as confusing as hell. Can't work out why it has a problem creating the preferences table. All of the files have been manually removed. The initial install was done using Devdemon Updater.

Comment: Are you using multiple site manager?  Do you have a site_id 0? I don't think that this is normal. Your default site should be site 1.  I don't think there is ever a site_id 0.

Comment: I'm also having this issue. Did it get resolved?

Comment: Sorry, Petroglyph. I never managed to solve this issue for that particular site. I just ended up using a non-EE solution entirely.